# How many Languages can we speak fluently

Tags: learning-methods, vocabulary, language-exchange

I am speaking many languages but I m pinned down each time and can't speak more than four languages fluently at the same time, I noticed that I can only keep 4 languages even if I try to learn a new one or maintain a language that used to speak I start to have 'uncontrolled glitches"(words from other languages that are used unwillingly and noticed on the go).

Anyone on the same situation ?

Comment: Welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange. While it would be interesting to know if there is inherent maximum of foreign languages that people can juggle, the question—as currently worded—is individual and not generalisable.

Comment: Can you describe "glitches" please. How i enterperate your question, the "glitch" is a word that isent described in a the language you are using. Need to be descriptive when translating from one language to another or possibly its just gramatically incorrect. E.i. I run da streets in ptown..lol naw but for real. I did door to door in da worst hoods of the bay yay area! Yeee stupid dumb and hyphy yadadamean bubu. We gona function tonight or wut? Where da beeezys gona be at saaann!! Translating a constructed language correctly requires the rules used. If none are available. Innovating is applica

Comment: Actually the glitch is more in this way, imagine you speak chineese english german and spainish, you're making a question how are you funny cat ?  you know those words in english and you know them in german the sentence in your mind is completely clear no confusions but when speaking those words you say How are you komisch cat unwillingly and notyfing the mistake on the go, this is the type of glitches i m asking for